# Using HTTP API and json to insert an embedded type in OrientDB

Tags: json, orientdb

I have defined a class 'Box' in OrientDB using the schema manager in studio.  'Box' has only one element - an embedded class 'Label'.

When I use this json to create a label

```
 {
    "@class": "Label",
        "boxUUID": "azxc",
        "validFrom": 0,
        "validTo": 100
}
```

in a POST command to 'Label', the insert  works.

But when I use it as below in a POST to 'Box' it fails.

```
{
    "@class": "Box",
    "Label": {
        "boxUUID": "azxc",
        "validFrom": 0,
        "validTo": 100
    }
}
```

With the following error message:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "reason": 500,
      "content": "com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OValidationException: The field 'Box.Label' has been declared as EMBEDDED but an incompatible type is used. Value: {boxUUID=azxc, validFrom=0, validTo=100}",
      "code": 500
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the correct format of the json for a class with an embedded class in OrientDB over the HTTP API?

Comment: Which command did you use in your first query?
Which version of OrientDb are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is:

- Put in the URL: localhost: 2480 / document / "your database name"
- Put in json "@" + name embedded class

[image]